# Getting files from a label - Perforce Java API

Tags: java, label, perforce

just wondering, how can I retrieve all the files and their revisions from a given label.

I have been looking at the API doc but can't seem to find anything relevant. I know there was a function .getFiles() from the old java implementation but now all there is to use is [this](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/core/ILabel.html)

Any advice would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `IServer.getDepotFiles` accepts a Perforce file spec as an argument.  You should be able to use something like `//...@label`.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/server/IServer.html#getDepotFiles(java.util.List, boolean)